# Should I apply for Test Job 1 or Test Job 2?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I'm not sure if this was actually supposed to show up on the public site or not, but there are currently 2 C#/.Net jobs listed at Stack Overflow with the titles [Test Job 1](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/166440/test-job-1-stack-overflow) and [Test Job 2](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/166441/test-job-2-stack-overflow). If the goal was to get them to show up, I suppose the tests were successful. If the goal was for them to be visible only internally, it looks like there may be a bug somewhere. ;)

Comment: Too bad there's not a Test Job 3 which [should be twice as good as either of those choices.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem)

Comment: We've closed these jobs so that they don't appear in search results anymore. We're investigating...

Comment: Consider applying to this LinkedIn job instead: https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/view/537771078

Comment: @Max That one will look great on a resume!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Testing is critical to ensuring a good user experience; here at Stack Overflow, we're fanatical about testing: I, personally, wear one of those beer helmets and giant foam fingers when testing as a testament to my fanaticism and love of beer.

As any programmer knows, some issues never show up until you're in production. Therefore, it's critical to test at *every* level of the process: locally, in staging, *and* after deployment. And to test in production, you gotta have test jobs - and a dedicated team of test users. So without further ado, I'd like to present our newest hires:

- [Test Employee 1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/618301/test-employee-1)
- [Test Employee 2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118676/test-employee-2)

These dedicated teammembers are the results of a minutes-long world-wide search for people skilled in typing while wearing giant foam fingers and having the word "test" in their names.

Please join me in welcoming them to the company!

#### Update

Test Employee 1 and Test Employee 2 have decided to move on to greener pastures after several long seconds of service. Please join me in thanking them for their work and wishing them well in all their future endeavors!

Comment: I demand pictures of said testing setup. :-p

Comment: Brave, Brave souls. Only the [finest GIF](https://media.giphy.com/media/3osxYrgM8gi9CDjcPu/giphy.gif) of gratitude will do.

Comment: Speaking of beer, the Most Interesting Man No Longer in the World [approves of this testing methodology](https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/MSDNBlogsFS/prod.evol.blogs.msdn.com/CommunityServer.Blogs.Components.WeblogFiles/00/00/01/32/02/metablogapi/8054.image_thumb_35C6E986.png).

Comment: [Chuck Norris](https://kvaes.files.wordpress.com/2017/07/testing-is-for-wimps-real-men-test-in-production.jpg) and [King Leonidas](http://i.imgur.com/1MiPnYz.jpg) also approve, so it must be a pretty solid strategy.